# how can we get the pdf file by using submit button

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

i want to make a pdf file with the help of php code if suppose i make a register form after click the submit button that form information must come to pdf file. is there any way to do. i got a one link but that PDF is not working properly
i have been searching but still i can't get the demo.

you guys can any one help me.

thanks

Comment: What is your question exactly? Also show the code you're using

Comment: I think he/she wants to dynamically create pdf from data user entered in the form and send that pdf to a user after submit is clicked. Right @nanacy?

Comment: It's unclear from your question what kind of help you need. You said you already have a link, but that the PDF is not working. Do you want help fixing that or do you need a general guide to creating a PDF using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try FPDF library. I am posting part of code I used for generating pdf dynamically in php.

`require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');`

`$frontpdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');`
`$frontpdf->AddPage();`
`$frontpdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);`
`$frontpdf->Cell(210, 230.19, $frontpdf->Image('./images/cover.jpg', 0, 0, 205, 230.19));`
`$frontpdf->Ln(218);`
`$frontpdf->Cell(110,6,$fname.' '.$lname,0);`
`$frontpdf->Ln();`
`$frontpdf->Cell(110,6,date('d.m.Y'),0);`
`$frontpdf->Output('./pdfs/your_data.pdf', 'F');`

For details see http://www.fpdf.org/

Use 'I' or 'D' instead of 'F' in last line if you want to send pdf file instead of saving it. You can use FPDF in php4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Set the action url of your form to a php file like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a pdf generator and i recommend you to use tcpdf:

http://www.tcpdf.org/

It is open source and when you download the library you have more than 50 or 60 how to use example scripts.

Unlike other open/source libraries i know that this one actually supports utf-8 (depends on the font used). I tested fpdf, dompdf and few others becouse i needed these characters in my documents: č, ć, ž, š, đ and that is the only library i could use for that.

If you need a specific example show me your code and i'll help you :)

Comment: FYI, dompdf will support UTF-8 in the 0.6.0 release (currently in beta).

Comment: If this is true then I apologize. Last time (10 month ago) tcpdf was only library with proper utf-8 support. It would be briliant if you have a example/link for utf-8 support in 0.6.x beta :)

Comment: No worries, the project wasn't actively developed for a while. You can see on the following PDF the expanded character set support when using an embedded font. http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/index.php?input_file=so4668484.htm&dompdf_ver=trunk&output_method=stream